# Raspberry Pi clean exit on CTRL+C in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, gpio

First of all, let me apologize as I can see that similar questions have been posted quite a few times in the past. However, as I am very unfamiliar with C, I need help confirming this.

I am trying to ensure that my program leaves a clean gpio if I interrupt it with CTRL+C. Easily done in python or java, but C proves to be a harder nut to crack for me, as I was led to believe that no try-catch-finally exists in C. Googling it, I found what I think may be the solution, but unexperienced as I am, I'm not sure it's done properly. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <signal.h>

void CleanGPIO() {
    pinMode(1,INPUT);
}
int main()
{

    wiringPiSetup();

    signal(SIGINT, CleanGPIO);
    pinMode(1, PWM_OUTPUT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        pwmWrite(1, i);
        delay(1);
    }
    for (int i = 1023; i >= 0; --i) {
        pwmWrite(1, i);
        delay(1);
    }
    pinMode(1,INPUT);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested it and it works as intended (pin 1 is set as IN after I interrupt it with CTRL+C), but I'm concerned if this is the safe way to do it, and if there is a better solution available.

Comment: That's the correct way to handle signals. You might need to add hooks for similar signals though.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick, I will look into it

Comment: *It works as intended ... is there a better solution?* This isn't a C question but one for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry I was not aware of the CodeReview section. Thank you for pointing it out Weather

Comment: there is also atexit http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is nearly right. You should also call `exit` in order to force the program to terminate (assuming you want to terminate immediately). The `exit` call takes a parameter which is the exit status to return to the caller (e.g., the shell). This should be non-zero for abnormal termination.

So, it should be:

```
void CleanGPIO() {
    pinMode(1,INPUT);
    exit(1);
}
```

If you don't want to exit from the handler but from `main` in a more controlled fashion you can set a flag instead and check the flag value inside the loops.

Comment: Thx, there was a slight delay between ctrl+c and actual termination and its gone now with your advice implemented

Answer (score 1):

calling any function which is not speficied as signal-safe from a signal handler is *undefined behaviour*. I suppose there is no such guarantee about `pinMode`.

The proper way would be to set a `volatile int` flag that you periodically check in your main loop.

```
volatile int terminating = 0;

void terminate(int sign) {
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
  terminating = 1;
}


int main() {

  for (...) {
    if (terminating) {
       // cleanup
       exit(1);
    }

  }

}
```

the call to `signal` inside the handler is to allow force terminating the program with a second ctrl+c in case proper clenup takes too long or is stuck for any reason.

Comment: Thank you dfogni, it looks like the safe solution I was looking for (also suggested by rghome as an alt approach,  if I am not mistaken)